# Crockford - Chapter 8 - page 86

Tags: javascript, regex

Crockford: "JavaScript: The Good Parts"

Chapter 8: Methods

**RegExp
regexp.exec(string)**

At the very end of page 86 there is a nice example
but I don't yet understand one small thing in it.

```
var text = '<html><body bgcolor=linen><p>' +
'This is <b>bold<\/b>!<\/p><\/body><\/html>';
```

Why are the `/` (forward slashes) escaped here?

I tried the example without them, seems to work just fine.

Comment: A wild guess: if it's used in a regex as a pattern, then it should be escaped as the delimiters in JS are forward slashes.

Comment: @HamZa — It can't be. The `\/` in the string literal would be parsed by the JS engine into `/` so the escape would never reach the regex engine.

Comment: @Quentin I'm reading your answer, sounds quite logical now you said it. +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a JavaScript string, there is no difference between `/` and `\/`.

Inside a `<script>` element the sequence `</script>` will end the element. To represent it inside a string as data, you can use `<\/script>`.

When generating JavaScript strings programatically, it is a common practise to escape all `/` characters as a defence against terminating scripts when used inside HTML.

This is just code that follows that pattern. There is no actual benefit achieved with this particular code.

Answer (score -1):

Probably this was supposed to be displayed as text on the webpage, instead of being parsed by browser. Check [this out](http://jsfiddle.net/Pnmsn/).

Two different behavior:

```
<html><body bgcolor=linen><p>This is <b>bold</b>!</p></body></html>
<html><body bgcolor=linen><p>This is <b>bold<\/b>!<\/p><\/body><\/html>
```

Comment: [This is wrong. As it's a JS (nothing to do with HTML) it'd output the same](http://jsfiddle.net/Pnmsn/1/)

Comment: @Maximus: I didn't get this. The second one doesn't make much sense in a webpage. When I type the second one in a web page and open it in a browser I see this "This is bold<\/b>!<\/p><\/body><\/html>".